# JavaScript StyleDisplay

Tags: javascript

I have to admit that I have only slight in programming, but there are a lot of syntax especially property values that I do not know and seem to have issues getting the result that I want.

My current code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
}
//-->
</script>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element:</p>
<a name="20140315A"></a>
<a href="#20140315A" onclick="toggle_visibility('20140315A');"><strong>London seminar 15 March 2014 [code:20140315A]</strong></a>
<div id="20140315A">
<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
</div>
<p><b>Note:</b> Outside DIV</p>
```

The result is that on first view, the hidden  will be shown. Which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to initially have the  hidden and only onclick then will show.

I have been trying different property values and have not been able to get the result I want.

I hope this is not a complicated case. Because I will be running this script in my WordPress, and I know nuts on CSS also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the style display for your div defaults to visible at first - you need to set its style either onload, or with a style attribute, as in -

```
style="display: none;"
```

Comment: <div style="display:none;" id="20140315A">

Basically, a quick lesson here: attributes are modifiers of tags. Tags are <div>, <html>, etc. An attribute is a key=value pair inside the angle brackets of a tag.

Comment: Thanks Thanks!!! It's superb!!! I'll have to admit that it's a great lesson! i made it <div id="20140315A" style="display:none;"> looks logical haha. Hey I really appreciate it man!!!